# What UUID(bluetooth LE) should I use to connect between my android app and lightblue app?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In this case, I hope to use LightBlue app to simulate as a "Heart Rate" Virtual Peripherals.

And wish to write the android app to connect this Virtual Peripherals.

But I really do not know that how to test read/write/... function between my app and LightBlue.

I try to use General's UUID in "Heart Rate" to filter the device I find, but it always return nothing.

What UUID should press in "startLeScan(UUID, callback)" function?

Where can I find it in LightBlue?

Then, there are some service UUID have only 16bits, how can I use it?

what should I do in callback function that function can help me to get the value on my LightBlue?

[this is the code that I reference to.](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/blob/master/BluetoothGatt/src/com/example/bluetoothgatt/MainActivity.java)

[and this code](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/blob/master/BluetoothGatt/src/com/example/bluetoothgatt/BeaconActivity.java)

UUID HUMIDITY_SERVICE     = UUID.fromString("f000aa20-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

UUID HUMIDITY_DATA_CHAR   = UUID.fromString("f000aa21-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

UUID HUMIDITY_CONFIG_CHAR = UUID.fromString("f000aa22-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

For one sensor, he use three UUID for SERVICE, DATA, CONFIG, it really confuses me!

how should I find all about that by LightBlue?

Please give me some suggestion.

Thanks a lot!

Devin

Answer (score 2):

The assigned service UUIDs are available [here](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx).  The Heart Rate Service is 0x180D.
The characteristics are listed on [this page](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicsHome.aspx).  The heart rate characteristics are 0x2A39,  0x2A8D and 0x2A37.

You should refer to the [Heart Rate Service specification](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/HRS.aspx) for details on the use of the characteristics

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've try to connect by UUID 0X180D. And the app have run into callback function " onConnectionStateChange()". after I run "gatt.discoverServices()", it never run into "onServicesDiscovered()". What should I do in app or lightblue to triggered function "onServicesDiscovered". it seems that lightblue never send service to app. or what should I do to get the service? Thank You